# How can I improve my regex expression to include whitespace and another option?

Tags: regex

My current regex expression works by finding everything before the first hyphen:

`(?<=^)(.*?)(?=-)`. For example in the following string:

> This is the text I want - not wanted text - more not wanted text

It finds "This is the text I want ". But in the following string:

> This is the-text I want - not wanted text - more not wanted text

It only finds "This is the".

I want to modify my regex expression to find everything up until the first " - ", including the whitespace. I also want the hyphen to be interchangeable with a "~". So I want to find everything up until the first " - " or " ~ ". I tried modifying it to:

`(?<=^)(.*?)(?=(\s-\s|\s~\s))`
However tis is not working. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Works fine with GNU `grep -P`, what regex engine are you using?

Comment: See my comments in the answer below. Because it's in wordpress I assumed it must be preg_match in php

Answer (score 2):

why are you using look-behind and look-ahead?  the whole expression is needlessly complex and the `%` is non-standard.

```
^(.*?)(?: [-~] |$)
```

will do what you want.  it starts at the start of the line, then matches everything until "hyphen or tilde with spaces" or the end of the line.  the `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, needed to group the two alternatives.

Comment: The % signs are copy pasted and should have been deleted. I am using regex in a wordpress plugin to specify the value of a custom field in the following way `%regex("%title%","^(.*?)(?: [-~] |$)","1")%`. When I use your code the custom field outputs this: `%regex(“Full-time Daytime Work ~ Wooloowin QLD – Find A Babysitter – Wooloowin QLD”,”^(.*?)(?: -~ |$)”,”1″)%`